# Help ! Flex Local connection

Tags: apache-flex, connection, local

i was building an application that use local connection and listens to another application that also uses local connection , the second application is sort of remote control for the first app. it invokes function of the listening app from outside.
anyway , everything works good on local host.
BUT 
once i have put the listening app on a server and try to work it , it does not connect anymore. 
any idea's?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a [cross-domain](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html) problem. You can create a cross-domain policy file, named crossdomain.xml, placed at the root level of a server. It looks basically like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
      <allow-access-from domain="www.company.com" />
 </cross-domain-policy>
```